# Bootstrap nav not full width in Electron

Tags: bootstrap-4, electron

I'm having difficulty in getting the navbar to full width and I'm not sure what is wrong as I tried using container-fluid and width 100%.

Here are my codes:

Index.html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    .container-fluid {
      padding: 0 !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
    }
  </style>
```

React Component

```
import React from 'react'

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{width: "100%"}}>
      <nav  className="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark">
        <ul className="navbar-nav">
          <li className="nav-item active">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div >
  )
}
```

What it look like in Electron
[image]

As you can see that the blue navbar is not filled up to the width of the electron.

What have I missed? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cause. I didn't know that I have accidentally placed a container in the app.js and that was the cause. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. Thanks